# DSolve gives a integration constant, but not the integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

The integration constant could be added in the notebook for the integration?

`DSolve[Derivative[1][F][x] == x, F[x], x]`
DSolve adds a integration constant.

$\left\{\left\{F(x)\to \frac{x^2}{2}+c_1\right\}\right\}$

`Integrate[f[x], x] = F[x]`
`(*( F[x]is a primitive function of f[x]*)`

`Integrate[x, x]` =  $\frac{x^2}{2}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the manual](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html): you can switch on integration constants if you wish, with [GeneratedParameters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeneratedParameters.html):

```
Integrate[x, x, GeneratedParameters -> C]
(*    x^2/2 + C[1]    *)
```

Comment: Thanks, but  then adding a + C to a indefinite integral calculation seems to be easier

Comment: Of course. The more fundamental question is: why do you need this constant? The definition of an indefinite integral is as an [equivalence class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) (equivalence by addition of any complex number) and should be treated as such a class in any calculations. Adding $+C$ is merely a way of _representing_ this equivalence; the constant $C$ never appears in any calculations. The constant is a symbol representing the equivalence operation (addition).

Comment: To me, it remains strange that MMA does not include that constant for the sake of completeness. 
The same goes for several other computer algebra packages.
Apparently it is difficult to put the constant in an algorithm so that it is mentioned in indeterminate integration.
It is a contradiction in the concept of MMA.

Comment: @janhardo It should be a question of convenience, not difficulty. It's not difficult to put in or take out. Which way makes using `Integrate` easier or causes less trouble? `Integrate` is used internally, and as Roman points out, the $C$ is hardly ever used (I wouldn't say never — `DSolve` fails on some IVPs precisely because of the constants). I can cite two strikes against the `+ C[1]`: The result cannot be autocompiled and the expression has an extra parameter. The first makes numerical computations harder and the second makes symbolic ones harder. So one often wants to leave it out.

Comment: @ Michael E2 It is a clear story what you write
Is still a lot attached to such a simple constant 
Got a better idea now, of what can play in MMA. :)